# How to make object like { id: value, ... } from array of objects whose entry has key id?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am going crazy trying to purify this function of this dirty const `initialState`!

```
const getInitialState = (entries) => {
  const initialState = {}
  entries.map(entry => initialState[entry.id] = 1)
  return initialState
}
```

Output I get, and is expected is

```
const obj = {
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
}
```

Thanks!

**CLARIFICATIONS**

Left out a bit, edited above.

I ended up reducing

```
const getInitialState = entries =>
  entries.reduce((initialState, entry) => ({
    ...initialState,
    [entry.id]: 1,
  }), {})
```

Also concerned with the lack of humour here and accusations of 'swearing'?

Comment: What is that first `getInitialState` supposed to do? It doesn't look right, not least because the result of `map` isn't used for anything.

Comment: what is your question here?

Comment: I am with TJ -  it looks likt it reduces to just retunring an object literal e.g. const getInitialState = (entries) => {}  BUT that can't be the intent here

Comment: I guess you want `entries.reduce((obj, entry) => (obj[entry.id] = 1, obj), {})`. No idea what you thought `[entry.id] = 1` or `...[e.id] = 1` would be doing though.

Comment: `[entry.id] = 1` also makes no sense. `1` isn't structured, you can't destructure it. Perhaps you meant `entry.id = 1`? (I mean, you *could* do `[entry.id] = [1]`, but that would be silly.)

Comment: Where is the swearword @T.J.Crowder ?

Comment: You can click on "edited x mins ago" and look at the history of what has been changed.

Comment: Ah, the bad ol' H word :) Whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first snippet would work fine if you'd actually assign the properties to `initialState`, like `entries.map(entry => initialState[entry.id] = 1)`. Also: using `forEach` instead of `map` makes a lot more sense in that case.

Apart from that, you can also use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to narrow your array down into a single Object.

I made the example a little verbose so that it's hopefully easier to understand.

```js
// I assume that your array looks something like this?
const data = [ { 'id': 1 }, { 'id': 2 }, { 'id': 3 }, { 'id': 4 } ];

const getInitialState = entries => {
  return entries.reduce((obj, entry) => {
    return Object.assign(obj, { [entry.id]: 1 });
  }, { });
};

console.log(getInitialState(data));
```

Comment: Don't use `Object.assign` for assigning a single key. That's just bloated and unperformant. Better take a look at *Felix Kling*s comment.

Comment: I posted the solution I ended up with. There was a bug in my code where I left out the part you showed in the example. Thank you for the help, I did not catch it before.

Comment: Yep, the solution I ended up going with does not use `Object.assign`.

Answer (score 0):

> trying to purify this function of this dirty const

I think you're a bit too dogmatic on this.

Besides that, `map()` ain't the right method, because a) it creates an extra Array, you don't use, cause you use map only to iterate, and b) anyways it's only available on Arrays.

If point b is no problem, you should use `forEach` to iterate, or `reduce` as in *Felix Kling*s comment.

But since ES6 has introduced kind of an iterable iterface, you could make this function handle any iterable structure by looping manually:

```
const getInitialState = (list) => {
    const initialState = {};
    for(let entry of list)
        initialState[entry.id] = 1;
    return initialState;
}
```

But I'd recomend two improvements:

- instead of an Object, use `const initialState = Object.create(null);` 
  This way initialState doesn't even inherit from Object, and you can be sure that *every key* on that object is own, no matter what.
- `getInitialState` is already pretty specific, why don't you make it more generic and more useful for another purpose

  ```
  const mapById = (list) => {
      const mapping = Object.create(null);
      for(let entry of list) 
          mapping[entry.id] = entry;
      return mapping;
  }
  ```

  that way you can still check wether there's an Object by this specific ID (like: `if(entriesById[someId]){ ... }`) and you also have a shortcut to fetch entries by id; faster than iterating the list for each ID you might want to get.